# A problem on analytic function on $\mathbb C-\{ 0 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be an analytic function in $\mathbb C-\{ 0 \}$ such that $f(1/{n\pi})$=sin $({n\pi})$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$. Is f(z)=sin(1/z) for all $z\in \mathbb C-\{0\}$ ?

Take g(z)=sin(1/z) and set $S =\{z\in \mathbb C:(f-g)(z)=0\}$ .The set S contain $\{1/{n\pi}:n \in \mathbb Z\}$ whose limit point does not in $\mathbb C-\{ 0 \}$, further i can't proceed.what is the result?Someone help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about $f(z)=e^z\sin(1/z)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider $h(z) = z \sin \left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$.